# Modules or classes?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Given these 2 approaches:

**Approach 1**

```
module DomainCRUD =
   let getWhere collection cond = ...

module DomainService =
   let getByCustomerId f customerId = 
      f(fun z -> z.CustomerId = customerId) 

// USAGE:  
let customerDomains = DomainCRUD.getWhere collection 
   |> DomainService.getByCustomerId customerId
```

---

**Approach 2**

```
type DomainCRUD(collection) =
   member x.GetWhere cond = ...

type DomainService(CRUD) =
   member x.GetByCustomerId customerId =
      CRUD.GetWhere(fun z -> z.CustomerId = customerId)

// USAGE:
let domainService = new DomainService(new DomainCRUD(collection))
let customerDomains = _domainService.GetByCustomerId(customerId)
```

Which would fit functional programming the most? I assume `approach 1` would, but also it feels a bit superfluous to call `DomainCRUD.GetWhere collection` each time.

Which would be the most flexible, and "readable"?

Comment: I'd say approach 1, if you're going to be using all those from F# only. If you want to see typical F# program structure, you can either check the [F# sources](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) or other [sources of awesome libraries like Deedle](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle). For example (in Deedle), there's [`Frame` data type](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/Frame.fs) and [`FrameModule`](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameModule.fs) containing most operations on frames.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458640/when-to-use-interfaces-and-when-to-use-higher-order-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 1, for the following reasons:

1. Functions associated with classes aren't [curried](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233158.aspx) but the ones associated with modules are. This means that you can partially apply a function inside a module to attain something that is typically done with a DI framework in OO code. (see Daniel's comment)
2. You can omit the module qualification `DomainCRUD.GetWhere` by simply `open DomainCrud`.
3. In addition to opening a module, you can mark it with [`[<AutoOpen>]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353721.aspx) or (conversely) [`[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340423.aspx) which provides additional flexibility not available with classes.
4. The module based approach is less verbose.

Comment: #1 is moot. Classes can have curried member functions.

Comment: Had no idea! Thx for the tip.